# Time complexity of doubly recursive function

Tags: math, recursion, time-complexity

So this is the code:

```
int test ( int n) 
{ 
   if (n ≤2) return 1; 
   else return test(n-2) * test(n-2); 
}
```

I'm not confident in how to reason about this recursive function. I tried mapping the N value to the recursion depth like so:

```
N = 2 -> 0 recursions
N = 4 -> 2
N = 8 -> 14
```

But to be honest I'm not sure this gets me anywhere (and just thinking about test(16) hurts my head.

Comment: you know that you can make the method much more efficient by changing `return test(n-2) * test(n-2)` into `{ int y=test(n-2); return y*y; }`? A single trivial change can turn a O(2^n) function into an O(n) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by writing out a recurrence relation for the total number of calls made:

- T(0) = T(1) = T(2) 1, since there's one total call (the initial call).
- T(n+2) = 2T(n) + 1, since there's one call for the initial call, plus two recursive calls to problems of size n.

Let's start by looking at the case where n is even. Then

- T(0) = 1
- T(2) = 1
- T(4) = 2T(2) + 1 = 3
- T(6) = 2T(4) + 1 = 7
- T(8) = 2T(6) + 1 = 15
- T(9) = 2T(8) + 1 = 31

Except for the 0 case, it looks like these values take on the pattern 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc. Notice that each of these is one less than a power of two: 1 = 2 - 1, 3 = 4 - 1, 7 = 8 - 1, etc. We can guess that what we're looking at has something to do with powers of two.

Going back to our sequence, we might make a guess that

- T(2) = 1 = 2<sup>1</sup> - 1
- T(4) = 3 = 2<sup>2</sup> - 1
- T(6) = 7 = 2<sup>3</sup> - 1
- ...
- T(2n) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

So if n is even, we have T(n) = 2<sup>n/2</sup> - 1 = (√2)<sup>n</sup> - 1. You can formalize this using a proof by induction.

For the odd case, we basically get the same thing:

- T(1) = 1
- T(3) = 2T(1) + 1 = 3
- T(5) = 2T(3) + 1 = 7
- T(7) = 2T(5) + 1 = 15
- T(9) = 2T(7) + 1 = 31
- ...
- T(2n+1) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

So if n is even, then T(n) = 2<sup>(n-1)/2</sup> - 1. Again, you can prove this by induction to formalize things if you'd like.